# Phonegap Windows app

Tags: android, ios, windows, cordova, kendo-ui

I have created a app using phonegap and kendoui.It works fine for android and IOS phone but when it comes to windows phone my code runs twice inside the function and then my app is stuck..Any suggestion regarding what I might be doing wrong or am I missing something when it comes to windows app?

Comment: Put some code so that users of SO can understand ur question properly

Comment: all the function call are working twice,for example if I go into the login screen of my app after clicking submit the same login screen is loaded again and then the app is stuck.But all function works fine in android and IOS phone.I want to know if there is anything specific to be done for developing app for windows using phonegap that is different from developing for android and IOS